# Spark removing executors in DataProc clusters

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

During a Spark job execution I'm constantly facing this following issue. Even the DataProc cluster was idle Spark driver is killing all the executors and I end up with one executor.

```
18/02/26 08:47:05 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 35 has been removed (new total is 2)
18/02/26 08:50:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 189.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6002) in 569184 ms on dse-dev-dataproc-w-53.c.k-ddh-lle.internal (executor 57) (499/500)
18/02/26 08:51:40 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 57
18/02/26 08:51:40 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 57
18/02/26 08:51:40 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 57
18/02/26 08:51:40 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 57 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 1)
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 57.
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 57 (epoch 7)
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 57 from BlockManagerMaster.
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(57, dse-dev-dataproc-w-53.c.k-ddh-lle.internal, 53072, None)
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Removed 57 successfully in removeExecutor
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Executor 57 on dse-dev-dataproc-w-53.c.k-ddh-lle.internal killed by driver.
18/02/26 08:51:42 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 57 has been removed (new total is 1)
```

Once the above task is completed when it starts the next Stage it looks for the shuffled data.

```
18/02/26 08:52:33 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 5 to 10.206.52.190:42676
18/02/26 08:52:33 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 7 to 10.206.52.157:45812
18/02/26 08:52:33 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 7 to 10.206.52.177:53612
18/02/26 08:52:33 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 5 to 10.206.52.166:41901
```

This window will hang for sometime and the tasks fail with the following exception.

```
18/02/26 09:12:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 21 requested
18/02/26 09:12:33 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 21
18/02/26 00:12:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 21 from BlockManagerMaster.
18/02/26 09:12:33 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1480517110174_0001_01_000049 on host: ip-10-138-114-125.ec2.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1480517110174_0001_01_000049
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Job executor settings:

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize  3840m
spark.driver.memory 16G
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors    100
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors    1
spark.executor.cores    6
spark.executor.id   driver
spark.executor.instances    20
spark.executor.memory   30G
spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled  False
spark.shuffle.service.enabled   true
spark.sql.catalogImplementation hive
spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata false
```

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue as [this one](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/42782/container-marked-as-failed-spark-yarn.html). You might try to set the minimum Yarn container size. It suggested in the post to set 1.5 times the size of the requested driver/executor memory.

Comment: Are you creating your cluster with "preemptive nodes"? If so, GCP may withdrawn them at anytime or after 24hs. This would cause your executors to be stopped, but the cluster should recover from that.

Comment: Another possible scenario is when the data in GCS changes while you are manipulating it with Hive/Spark. Check if you have any concurrent updates in you GCS bucket.